# PHP SQL Select From Where

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some difficulty running some SQL code.

What I am trying to do is, find a row that contains the correct username, and then get a value from that correct row.

This is my SQL in the php:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE joined='$username' GET name")
```

As you can see, it looks for a username in users and then once found, it must GET a value from the correct row.

How do I do that?

Comment: It's just a sample, as I am saying I want to GET the value of name.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need some additional PHP code (a call to mysql_fetch_array) to process the result resource returned by MySQL.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE joined='$username'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row['name'];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM users WHERE joined='$username' ")
```

Just select the right column in your 'select clause' like above.

Edit: If you are just starting out though, you might want to follow a tutorial like this [one](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Data-Object/PDO-Tutorial-P842.html) which should take you through a nice step by step (and more importantly up to date functions) that will get you started.

Comment: a hint for avoiding sql injection would be nice ;)

Comment: @nyarlathotep that would be too overwhelming for OP. He/She is not yet familiar with mysql syntax.

Comment: @nyarlathotep Good point. Answer edited with a link to a nice step by step and in depth tutorial.

Comment: @aspirin: the concept can never be mentioned early enough - i would say as soon as DB access is involved it should be a topic ;) I agree, though, that solving the problem with syntax is more important. that's why I wrote "a hint [...] would be *nice*" ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE joined='$username'")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE joined='$username'");

$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

$name = $r['user_name']; // replace user_name with the column name of your table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE joined='$username' ")
```

Read documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html