# Getting ID of Variable in database

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the id of an item in the database, set it to a variable, and use it. I'm quite new to all this coding stuff. I'm basing this on.

http://jameshamilton.eu/content/simple-php-shopping-cart-tutorial?PHPSESSID=99d373741727e3010a32319f1ebed001

```
cart.php?action=add&pdin=fbs

$product = $_GET[pdin];
```

I can't use an integer for 'pdin' so, id like to use its corresponding id which is an integer and plug it into this line of code which only takes integers?

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE pdin = %d;", $product);
```

so in i would take $product = 'pdin' find it's id $id = 'id' and plug it in to the above code

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = %d;", $id);
```

I tried reading up on this sql FROM SELECT WHERE... confused me some

Comment: You can do a join instead.

Comment: How did you link the product `id` to the `pdin` reference ?

Comment: if you have `pdin` and `id` both in `products` then why do you need to find `id` from result of using `pdin` ?

Comment: Do we have an obligatory "escape your SQL" answer can link people to?

Comment: antoox. That's the answer i'm seeking. How to i get the string that i got from the url and match it to its ID. In other words, I have a have a database with an ID (int) and a PDIN (string) already defined within it. I need to get the ID of the PDIN and place it the $sql. And this looks pretty similar to my question. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983714/php-sql-select-from-where>. I'm going to study this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I'm sorry i didn't explain it all that well last night. I have a limited brain battery per day, and last night it was depleted.

What i wanted was quite simple. I wanted to find an items associated id in the database.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pdin = '$product'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $productID = $row['id'];
}
```

Now that parts done and returns the correct id. And the 'item exists' function fires correctly.

```
//function to check if a product exists
function productExists($productID) {
    //use sprintf to make sure that $productID is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = %d;", $productID); 

return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > 0;
}
```

So, Mark and Michal Hatak; When you where talking about using quotations on keys, does that mean...

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM products WHERE 'id' = %d;", $productID);
```

putting quotations around things like 'id'? And it's for security?
Forgive me, I'm a new graphic designer and not adept at code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a prepared statement which would also make yourself a bit safer from SQL injection. What database interface are you using from php to mysql?

Here's one option:

```
$product = $_GET['pdin'];
$stmt = $db->Prepare("select * from products where pdin = ?");
$res = $db->GetAssoc($stmt,$product);
```

Answer (score 0):

btw,
if you acces array items via key, always use quotations (`'` or `"`) otherwise PHP (unnecessary) first check, if key is constant

Comment: I wouldn't say "unnecessary", it's outright dangerous. But this should be a comment as it doesn't answer his question.